# MVC @Html.DropDownList

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a @Html.DropDownList in the View. I like to default the value of what is select.
Note that @Html.DropDownList accepts a list. Not sure if there is a parameter to set it to a default value that is in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pre select a value that is already in your list, then you need to set `Selected = true` on the `SelectListItem`.

There is also an option to pass an "option label" into the Html.DropDownList method but this is for rendering something like "Please choose a value from the list".

Answer (score 0):

I believe something along these lines should work for you:

```
@Html.DropDownList("HtmlHelper", SelectList, new { @Value = valueToSelect });
```

**Edit:**

This should work for you:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Crd", (SelectList)ViewBag.CrdinatorSelectList, new { @Value = "James Brick" })
```

If you are wanting to get the Value from your ViewBag or ViewData you can try the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Crd", (SelectList)ViewBag.CrdinatorSelectList, new { @Value = ViewBag.Property })
@Html.DropDownList("Crd", (SelectList)ViewBag.CrdinatorSelectList, new { @Value = ViewData["Property"] })
```

Comment: I have something like: @Html.DropDownList("Crd", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CrdinatorSelectList, "", new { @Value = James Brick" })  where i know James Brick is in the list but did not select anything for me. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks Jmein. I tried  @Html.DropDownList("Crd", (SelectList)(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CrdinatorSelectList, "", new { @Value = "James Brick" }) but still no luck. Am I missing something

Comment: Also how do I pass a ViewBag in place of "James Brick"